# how to create a fullscreen route in react.js

Tags: reactjs, router

I have a react app and am wanting to create a component that has a unique url that also has none of the navigation of the rest of the site (like a fullscreen preview). I have hunted all over for how how to do this but not really found anything.
My component route looks like this

```
                <Route path='/embed/:documentid' component={Embed} />
```

My app looks like this

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

//LAYOUT
import './scss/a_main.scss';
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar';

//PAGES
import MyLibrary from './components/pages/MyLibrary';
import Home from './components/pages/Home';
import Embed from './components/documentEmbed/embed';
// AUTH
import Register from './components/auth/Register';
import Login from './components/auth/Login';
import Alerts from './components/layout/Alerts';
import PrivateRoute from './components/auth/PrivateRoute';
import AuthState from './context/auth/AuthState';
import setAuthToken from './utils/setAuthToken';

//STATES

import DocumentState from './context/Document/DocumentState';

//UTILS
import AlertState from './context/alert/AlertState';

//GUI
import DocumentEditor from './components/documentEditor/documentEditor';
import GUIDev from './components/pages/GUIDev';

if (localStorage.token) {
  setAuthToken(localStorage.token);
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <AuthState>
      <DocumentState>
        <AlertState>
          <Router>
            <Fragment>
              <Navbar />
              <Alerts />
              <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute exact path='/' component={Home} />
                <Route exact path='/register' component={Register} />
                <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
                <Route exact path='/guidev' component={GUIDev} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path='/mylibrary' component={MyLibrary} />

                <PrivateRoute exact path='/myDocs' component={DocumentEditor} />
              </Switch>
            </Fragment>
          </Router>
        </AlertState>
      </DocumentState>
    </AuthState>
  );
};

export default App;
```

If I put the route embed component in this page anywhere I end up seeing the nav bar somewhere on the page.

## I HAVE TRIED

I thought I could put it in another hierachy and use logic to determine which but I don't know what variable to use that would switch between hierarchy. example below (with psuedo code for logic)

```
          <Router>
{(example logic here)}
<Fragment>
                <Route path='/embed/:documentid' component={Embed} />

</fragment>
{(else)}
            <Fragment>
              <Navbar />
              <Alerts />
              <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute exact path='/' component={Home} />
                <Route exact path='/register' component={Register} />
                <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
                <Route exact path='/guidev' component={GUIDev} />
                <Route path='/embed/:documentid' component={Embed} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path='/mylibrary' component={MyLibrary} />

                <PrivateRoute exact path='/myDocs' component={DocumentEditor} />
              </Switch>
            </Fragment>
          </Router>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I figured out a simple solution to my problem. I removed the NavBar component from the App.js hierachy and just put it in where I needed it

```
  <Router>
{(example logic here)}
<Fragment>
                <Route path='/embed/:documentid' component={Embed} />

</fragment>
{(else)}
            <Fragment>
 ///NAVBAR DELETED FROM HERE
              <Alerts />
              <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute exact path='/' component={Home} />
                <Route exact path='/register' component={Register} />
                <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
                <Route exact path='/guidev' component={GUIDev} />
                <Route path='/embed/:documentid' component={Embed} />
                <PrivateRoute exact path='/mylibrary' component={MyLibrary} />

                <PrivateRoute exact path='/myDocs' component={DocumentEditor} />
              </Switch>
            </Fragment>
          </Router>
```

This was a simple change for this use-case I understand this may not be practical if there were lots of other components in the hierarchy but it worked for me.

I then just put the navbar into the pages separatley

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) for that? For example
**FullscreenContext.js**

```js
// create the context with necessary keys
const FullScreenContext = createContext({
  fullscreen: false
});

// consumer if you want to use it with nesting
export const FullScreenContextConsumer = FullScreenContext.Consumer;

// provider to provide it to the components
export const FullScreenContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isFullScreen, setIsFullScreen] = useState(false);
  
  const enableFullScreen = () => setIsFullScreen(true);
  const disableFullScreen = () => setIsFullScreen(false);

  return (
    <FullScreenContext.Provider value={{fullscreen: isFullScreen}}>
      {children}
    </FullScreenContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default FullScreenContext; // the default export, for `useContext(..)`
```

**App.js**

```js
const App = () => {
  const { fullscreen } = useContext(FullScreenContext);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Fragment>
        { !fullscreen && <Navbar /> }
        <Switch>
        </Switch>
      </Fragment>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

**YourFullScreenPage.js**

```js
export default () => {
  const { enableFullScreen, disableFullScreen } = useContext(FullScreenContext);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    enableFullScreen(); // enable it on mount
    return () => disableFullScreen(); // disable it again on unmount
  }, [])
}
```

Make sure you wrap your components where needed with the provider, for example in **index.js**

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <FullScreenContextProvider>
    <App />
  </FullScreenContextProvider>
)
```

You could even go as far as creating a custom component for wrapping fullscreen pages, with the same principle as `YourFullScreenPage.js`, do what suits your needs!

*P.S. This code was written from my head, so I'm not sure if it will compile fine*

Comment: Thanks Thimma I was hoping to do it without using context and hooks or redux though as I haven't so far in the app and would prefer to keep it that way if I can

Comment: You could refer a user with a parameter in the url like `https://yourweb.site/info?noNav=true` and check if that parameter is true in the navbar component, if it is, hide it